# Javascript Named Function Expressions in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Why does the following code not work in Internet Explorer (I've only tested in IE8 so far):

```
(function(){
  this.foo = function foo(){};

  foo.prototype = {
    bar:function(){
      return 'bar';
    }
  };
})();

var x = new foo;
console.log(x.bar()) // Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

If I change `foo`'s assignment to the following, the code works just fine:

```
var foo = this.foo = function(){};
```

I imagine it's something to do with named functions in IE's Javascript engine. The code works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE has a lot of problems with named function expressions.  As you said in your question, stick with this:

```
this.foo = function (){};
```

For an in-depth, grueling read on this topic, check out [this link](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)

The short of it is that the inner, named function expression is treated as a function **declaration**, and hoisted up to places it should never, ever be.

Comment: Just to add a bit more detail -- named function expressions actually create two distinct objects in IE. See example #3 in http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs

Comment: You shouldn't have to avoid named functions because of this. As a rule of thumb, treat function foo() {} the same way you would a var declaration and only afterwards assign it to any property.

Comment: To anyone that wants to use NFE's for code organization reasons, but can't because of support, one workaround is to slide a comment with the function name in the spot where the function name would normally go. E.g., `(function /* myFunctionName */ () {...}());` This makes it easy to replace with the real thing later and is almost as readable.

Comment: It looks like this hasn't been updated since 2014 and IE8.  How do IE10 and IE11 handle named function expressions?

Answer (score 5):

In IE, the usage of `foo.prototype` is "ambigious" because NFE identifiers are leaked to the containing scope.
Since the local leaked foo is closer than the global foo, `foo.prototype` will
augment the local `foo`, not `window.foo`.

After you leave the outer function, the local `foo` is lost and the global `foo` doesn't have `.prototype.bar`
for the above reasons.

You can resolve the ambiguity by:

```
(function(){
  this.foo = function foo(){};

  this.foo.prototype = {
    bar:function(){
      return 'bar';
    }
  };
})();

var x = new foo;
console.log(x.bar()) //"bar"
```