# how to get a property name which represent a function in JS

Tags: javascript, function

This is some JS code

```
var methodArr = ['firstFunc','secondFunc','thirdFunc'];

for(var i in methodArr)
{

    window[methodName] = function()
    {
        console.log(methodName);
    }
}
```

My problem is that how to get the name of a function in JS.

In JS, use `this.callee.name.toString()` can get the function name. But in this situation, it is a `null` value. How can i get the `'funName'` string?

Sorry, I didn't make it clear.
I want to create functions in a for loop, all these functions has almost the same implementation which need its name. But others can call these functions use different name.I want to know what `methodName` function is called.

Comment: you get null because its an anonymous function

Comment: In which case don't you know the name of your function in advance? I mean, if the name of the function is created by php, asp or anything else, you can also get it inside the function

Comment: are you trying this for recursion?

Comment: Is there any way to get 'funName' string in this situation?

Comment: try `function funName(){}` to declare a named function

Comment: I create this funtion in a for loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get anonymous function name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178305/get-anonymous-function-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems a scope problem.

Try this:

```
var methodArr = ['firstFunc','secondFunc','thirdFunc'];
for(var i in methodArr) {
    var methodName = methodArr[i]; // <---- this line missed in your code?

    window[methodName] = (function(methodName) {
        return function() {
            console.log(methodName);
        }
    })(methodName);
}

window['secondFunc'](); // output: secondFunc
```

Comment: It works. http://jsfiddle.net/Yg822/ . If your code still not working then post your exact problem and the exact code.

Comment: Sorry，I tried it in a wrong way before.It works.Helps a lot,Thank u.