# how to get js method name from inside the method

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, methods

I want to get current method name directly from this method body, my code which does not work is:

```
var myFunction = function(){
    console.log(arguments.callee.name); // output must be "myFunction" 
}


This works excellently

function myFunction() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.name); // output is "myFunction" 
}
```

what do you suggest me, is there any way to make this work?
I searched for google more and more but did not find smth. helpful

Comment: It's an anoymous function, how can have a name?

Comment: @adricadar is absolutely right. It simply has no name.  You can, however, work around this by simply giving it one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178305/get-anonymous-function-name for how to do this and what implications it has (especially IE).

Comment: okay, is there any way to get variable name which value is this anonymous function? in the case "myFunction"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to give a **name** to the function:

```
var myMethod = function myMethod () {    
    console.log(arguments.callee.name); // output is "myMethod"
};
```

I don't like this way at all but it works in concrete task

Answer (score 2):

The function is **anonymous**, has no name.

To get the variable name, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548885/print-display-a-javascript-variables-name-instead-of-its-value).

**Solution 1**:
Try to create an `object` that has a `property` and you **iterate** through properties and display the name of the `property`.

```
var x = {
    myFunction : function(){      
    }
};

for(var variable in x)
{
    console.log(variable);
}
```

**Solution 2:**
I tried to make an **workaround**. I consider that the `property` is the **first** from the object and i try do display the name of the `property`.

```
var funcTest = function() {   
    for(var variable in this) {
        console.log(variable);
        break;
    }
} 

var x = {  myFunction : funcTest  };
x.myFunction(); // myFunction

var y = { secondFunction : funcTest }
y.secondFunction(); // secondFunction
```

Comment: this is not usable for me (((

Comment: i dont think that answers his question. He wants to know if it is possible to know the function name from inside the function itself