# Anonymous function's name

Tags: javascript

I want to get the [name of an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178305/get-anonymous-function-name).

The typical answer is

```
var aName = function a(){};
```

Which gives this

```
aName.name === "a"        // true
```

But I found that this works too:

```
var a = function a(){};
```

Which gives this

```
a.name === "a"            // true
typeof a === "function"   // true
```

However, I feel like I'm asking for trouble there, as I'm overwriting names. Are there any repercussions for using such a syntax?

Comment: The second name is useful for two things:

- debugging (you'll see that in stack)
- recusion - you can call that from inside of the function

Comment: @TomasRandus I'm not sure which you're referring to?

Comment: As in Javascript functions are objects, don't see really any difference between var a = function a() {}; and function a() {};

Comment: I feel like if you give your function a name, it's not an anonymous function anymore

Comment: I hope understand the quesition well. The 'a' is not overwriting of the name. 'aName' is name of varieble that reffers to function 'a'. The name of the function 'a' is not required, the function can be anonymous. And there are two reasons for doing that: better debugging and recusion.

Comment: @TomasRandus No I'm referring to the second form where `var a = function a(){}`

Comment: "I want to get the name of an anonymous function." Anonymous function does not have the name. [Different Ways of Defining Functions in JavaScript](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/different-ways-of-defining-functions-in-javascript-this-is-madness/).

Comment: @WisdmLabs You are of course technically right, but you understand the gist of the maybe poorly-phrased question. I want the name of a locally scoped function.

Comment: `var v = function fun(){}` - In this case the function name is only accessible within the function.

Comment: "*I'm overwriting names*" - What? Where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two approaches are almost identical, the only difference is that in the second you are shadowing `a` as the variable identifier with `a` as the function identifier (when `a` is used inside the `a` function).

About shadowing: [Variable shadowing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript)

Comment: Which is why `a.name` works as expected! Yes this makes sense.

Comment: @hbob: He meant that you're shadowing `a` with `a` *inside the `a` function scope*. The outer variable (`a`) works just the very same as the `aname` variable in your first example.

Comment: @Bergi I know, which is why I chose his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't overwriting anything.

The only way the `.name` property can be set is if you declare the function with a name.

```
function nameHere() {

}
```

If the function is named, then the name property will use that name.

If the function isn't named, then it is anonymous.

```
var nameHere = function() {

};
```

There is no (proper) way to get the name of the variable that an anonymous function is assigned to.