# Determine the property name of an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to determine the property name of an anonymous function within the function?  For instance...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $={};
            $.fn={};
            $.fn.somePropertyName = function() {
                console.log(this); // Object { somePropertyName=function()}
                //How do I get "somePropertyName" here?
            };
            $.fn.somePropertyName()
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body> 
</html>
```

My purpose is so I don't need to type out "myPluginName" twice when creating jQuery plugins.  Not that I am lazy, but don't want the chance of a difference.

```
$.fn.myPluginName= function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        // Somehow get the property name "myPluginName" here.
        $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPluginName');
    }    
};
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code you've tried to use to solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get anonymous function name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178305/get-anonymous-function-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a routine which finds a particular function on an object, and returns the property key:

```
function find_fn(obj, fn) {
  let (var i in obj) if (obj[i] === fn) return i;
}

function name(fn) {
  return find_fn($.fn, fn);
}
```

Now use the trick of binding the function to itself, so the function can refer to itself from within itself using `this`:

```
$.fn.foo = function() { console.log('my name is', name(this); }
$.fn.foo = $.fn.foo.bind($.fn.foo);
$.fn.foo();
```

However, it might be easier to simply do:

```
const FUNCNAME = 'somePropertyName';
$.fn[FUNCNAME] = function() {
  console.log("I am", FUNCNAME);
};
```

If you mistype FUNCNAME now, you'll get a ReferenceError or something.

Comment: Thanks torazburo,  So, only way is to define a constant?

Comment: is `find_fn()` valid?  I am getting a syntax error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'var'  let (var i in obj) if (obj[i] === fn) return i;`