# Is it possible to get the name of an anonymous JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, logging

Is it possible to get the name of an anonymous function that declared as follows?

```
var F = function(){};
```

At first sight, the answer is no, but apparently the browsers know and hold the function name:

```
var F = function(){};
var x = new F();
console.log(x.constructor);   // function F()
```

(Firefox)

```
var F = function(){};
var x = new F();
console.log(x);    // F {}
```

(Chrome)

Is this name somehow accessible? I need it mainly for error logging, so the solution doesn't have to be cross-browser.

**Edit for clarification:**

I'm getting an objects from external code that I need to know their types, therefore obvious answers like using another declaration ways are not what I'm searching.

Comment: I've run into a similar issue with error logging. In `Error.stack` browsers will include the name of the token, you can use that.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get anonymous function name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178305/get-anonymous-function-name)

Comment: An anonymous function is nameless isn't? You want the variable name under which is stored.

Comment: @whd The accepted answer of that question is not the answer I searched. I clarified it in my question.

Comment: @MinusFour Not exactly, the name apparently stored in the function object at the declaration.

Comment: `x.constructor.name`

Comment: @ndugger `F.name` won't work when `F` is anonymous.

Comment: You need to know "their types" as in "string", "boolean", "function"? Or you need to know the variable name the function you received is originally assigned to?

Comment: @SoEzPz I need to know the variable name

Answer (score 2):

In the use-case that you're trying, it's possible that there can be more than one variable holding the same anonymous function.

ie, it can go on like:

```
var F = function(){};
var x = new F();
var x2 = x;
var x3 = x;
var blah = x3;
```

So, now we have more than one name to look for. And the first thing I thought of is to loop through all the objects under window and print their name which is having the same method as the value.

So, you'd think of something like:

```
for each (item in window){
   if (myfunc == item){
      console.log(/*Somehow print the actual name of the item */)
   }
}
```

But, it doesn't work that way since, now `item` is another variable, and look like there is no built-in property that gives the variable name. 
May be, have a look at [Variable name as a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript) , not that it helps here, though...

So, finally, since you mentioned you're trying to do error logging, thought of using stack-traces.  Don't know if it will apply in your situation, may be still a bit enlightening :)

And this is how it goes:
(To be warned, this is a hack)

```
var myFunction = function(){   
  var err = new Error();   
  console.log(err.stack) 
} 
myFunction();
```

will output something like:

```
myFunction@debugger eval code:3:17
@debugger eval code:6:5
@debugger eval code:1:15
```

And, taking that to the next level:

```
var myFunction = function(){   
  var err = new Error();   
  console.log(err.stack.split("@")[0]) 
 /* split the stack-trace string and get the first word before @ */
} 
myFunction();
```

Now, the output for that will be:

```
myFunction
```

Which, indeed is the name of the variable that is holding the anonymous function.

Note: This answer is inspired by the question [How can I get a Javascript stack trace when I throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception)

*Have tried this only in Firefox, there's a chance the stack-trace might be different elsewhere.*

**Edit:**
Failed to notice your edit, this might need editing of declarations, which breaks your use-case. :(